# How to add an alt tag to the auto featured image posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, alt

I'm a total beginner to the PHP, so sorry if my question will sound silly.

So, I am using a WordPress plugin called [Automatic Featured Image Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/). It does a great job creating a draft post from a newly uploaded image. Apart from the plugin, I have also added this filter to the functions.php file which adds the image into the post:

```
    add_filter( 'afip_new_post_content', 'myprefix_change_afip_post_content', 10, 2 );
/* Grabs the image source for the newly created image and inserts it
 * into the new post content along with a one line paragraph. */
function myprefix_change_afip_post_content( $post_content, $attachment_id ) {
    $my_uploaded_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );

    $post_content = '<p>This is my new uploaded image....</p>';
    $post_content .= '<img src="' . $my_uploaded_image[0] . '">';
    return $post_content;
}
```

So, my question is - how to add an alt image to this code? The alt image should be the same as the title of the new post. Do I have to make another function for this? I know the first thing I have to do is to add alt="" into the  tag. But how do I get the title of the post to appear into the alt? Here's a link to the code of the plugin - [enter link description here](https://justpaste.it/6pvjq)

Answer (score 0):

As promised the Image's 'alt' text is stored as a string in wp_postmeta with the meta_key of  '`_wp_attachment_image_alt`'.

As you probably already know you can load it with a simple get_post_meta() like so:

```
$alt_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm kind of a TOTAL noob. I am not sure if I have to make another filter? Because adding an $alt_text as an argument doesn't work